# Visual Studio MAC: CSC Errors

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, system

I just updated my Visual Studio Mac version to Preview 4 (7.0 build 1566).

I am getting a lot of errors when compiling a project I could correctly compile before the update.
The erros are all like this one:
**CSC: Error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Object' is not defined or imported (CS0518)**

Is anyone experiencing the same problems? How could I solve them?

Comment: Did your `System` reference disappear from your references?

Comment: How do I check it? Sorry, I am a very newbie of VS

Comment: Look in your References folder in the project file tree and make sure that `System` is in there, if it isn't, you'll need to add the reference back in. I'm not sure about the Mac, but on Windows this is done by right clicking the folder and selecting "Add Reference".

Comment: Checked. The references are there. System, System.Core, System.Xml, System.Xml.Linq

Comment: I also tried to remove and re-add the references

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.
Checking the compilation command, it seems to refer to .Net portable, despite having selected .Net Standard in Options. Not sure how to change it.